# Would a "this site uses cookies" notice be sufficient under the GDPR for cookies from other domains

Tags: cookie, gdpr, notification

I'm using a third-party analytics tool that sets a cookie to track the user for analytics purposes (for tracking conversions) as soon as the user hits the page. The analytics service does not store any personal information of that user like name, age, etc.

The trick is that the cookie is being set on a different domain (the domain of the analytics tool). Would the "this site uses cookies..." banner on my site be sufficient in this case?

Answer (score -1):

Yes it would be sufficient, but make sure in the privacy policy you mention about the third party cookies.

Comment: Such a short answer is not high quality.  Can you add more about why you think this?  Links to references or stories from your own experience would make this answer much better.